# Using extension methods with runtime assemblies

Tags: c#, reflection, methods

Is there any way to use extension methods on a class that has been dynamically created using Relection.Emit?  For example:

```
 class somewhere
 {
     somewhere()
     {
         // define the type here using ReflectionEmit, etc.
         Type tableType = CreateTableType(...table parameters...);

         var table = Activator.CreateInstance(tableType);
         table.Shuffle();
     } 
 }

 //... elsewhere
 public class static TableTypeExtensions   
 {
      public static Table Shuffle( this Table t)  
      {   
          ...
      }
 }
```

But I don't have the class by name "Table", only Type tableType available.
Is there any way around this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a common base class for your TableType and define the extension method on that. This way your extension method should be available for the derived classes as well.

Comment: I used this in my final code.  It makes more sense to me to add functionality to a class than to an interface.

Answer (score 4):

Make the dynamic class implement an interface (an empty one if you want), add extensions to the interface.

Comment: @downvoter Why the downvote?  It's a good and common solution to the OP's question "Is there any way to use extension methods on a class that has been dynamically created using Relection.Emit?".

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at what you're asking.

You're asking how to get the extension method to operate on your object instance.

Obviously, for this to work, it has to be a `Table`, otherwise your question makes no sense.

So just cast it to `Table`:

```
var table = (Table)Activator.CreateInstance(tableType);
```

and you can call your extension method just fine.

Comment: You don't have to cast it to it's base class. The extension method is available on the derived types as well.

Comment: If he's constructing the type through reflection, he doesn't have the derived type as a "type" per se, only the object instance. And the result of Activator.CreateInstance is of type `object`. The cast is just to get the compiler to recognize the correct type.

Comment: I think my sample is too simplistic.  I don't actually have a Table class defined anywhere.   The tableType is defined by
  
recordType = moduleBuilder.DefineType("name");
tableType = typeof(BindingList<>).MakeGenericType(recordType);

Comment: @Lasse: Good point. I read your answer as saying he needed to cast to Table to get the extension methods, my bad :-)

Comment: If the question has been answered, you should accept the answer that answered it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've got running code now but still testing for efficiency.  Actually the final code will use parts of several answers.  Too bad I can't check more than one.  I'll post it when done.

Answer (score 0):

In your `somewhere` code do you have reference to the type `Table`? If so you can:

```
 Type tableType = CreateTableType(...table parameters...);

 var table = Activator.CreateInstance(tableType) as Table;
 table.Shuffle();
```

Comment: You should use a cast, not `as`.